# Google charts change date format

Tags: php, javascript, drupal-7

i want date in google chart x-axis in the format of(1 2 3,...only date), but i passed date values using php from drupal views in the fornat(1 mar 2013).I want 1 mar 2013 in table which comes below the chart and only date(1,2,3,...)in chart x-axis. Is it possible?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes possible you use `Date API` Module... 
try this code

```
 <?php
    $form['payment_expirationDate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Expiration Date:'),
    '#date_format' => 'm-Y',
    '#default_value' => $expirationDate,
    '#date_year_range' => '-1:+10',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#date_label_position' => 'within'
     ); 
    ?>
```